# precondition to check more than one record in dml file using liquibase changeset and yaml format

Tags: yaml, liquibase

I have a precondition to check more than one record in DML file using Liquibase changeSet and YAML format:

My requirement to add precondition which check record should exist:

```yaml
- changeSet:
  id: 18.5.1
  author: saggarwal
  comment: PROD-5303 | DELETE | TEMPLATE_COLUMN_MAPPPING | ATT
  preConditions: 
    - onFail: MARK_RAN
    - sqlCheck:
    -not:
        expectedResult: 0
        sql: select count(*) from es_email;
  changes:
    - delete: 
        tableName: es_email
        where: template_id =select id from abc where name= 'XYZ';
```

But it is not working. How can we check this? Please give some example.
In XML we do like:

```xml
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
<not>
    <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">
        select count(*) from es_email;
    </sqlCheck>
</not>
</preConditions>
```

...but in YAML?

Comment: Your YAML fails to parse because there is no space after the `-` in `not:`. I suspect that won't solve your problem, though. I don't know anything about Liquibase, but there are structural differences between your XML and your YAML. In the XML, `sqlCheck` is a child of `not`, but in the YAML they're siblings.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem with your YAML is that there's no space after the `-` in `-not:`, so it [doesn't parse](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=-+changeSet%3A%0A++id%3A+18.5.1%0A++author%3A+saggarwal%0A++comment%3A+PROD-5303+%7C+DELETE+%7C+TEMPLATE_COLUMN_MAPPPING+%7C+ATT%0A++preConditions%3A+%0A++++-+onFail%3A+MARK_RAN%0A++++-+sqlCheck%3A%0A++++-not%3A%0A++++++++expectedResult%3A+0%0A++++++++sql%3A+select+count(*)+from+es_email%3B%0A++changes%3A%0A++++-+delete%3A+%0A++++++++tableName%3A+es_email%0A++++++++where%3A+template_id+%3Dselect+id+from+abc+where+name%3D+%27XYZ%27%3B&type=json). There are other problems, however, the most apparent of which is that in your XML, `sqlCheck` is a child of `not`, but in your YAML they are siblings.

The documentation for YAML in Liquibase is hilariously bad. However, googling "Liquibase YAML sqlCheck" leads us to [the tests](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/5d9981d6bedee5eab994fa5e54c18bcfb43af441/liquibase-core/src/test/resources/liquibase/parser/core/yaml/testCasesChangeLog.yaml#L73-L99), a quick survey of which suggest the following refinement to your YAML:

```
preConditions: 
  - onFail: MARK_RAN
  - not:
    - sqlCheck:
        expectedResult: 0
        sql: select count(*) from es_email;
```